# How can I reverse the words in a string in R without using strsplit?

Tags: r

I am trying to take a string and reverse the words without replying on `strsplit` in R. Specifically, I need to only use base R commands. If I have:

```
string1 <- "This is a string with words"
```

I would like to be able to get

```
"words with string a is This"
```

The biggest challenge for me is that I am not sure if there exist ways to access the elements of a string by indexing (unlike in Python). Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `strsplit` is a base R command.

Comment: In python words, strings in R is not iterable and characters in a string cannot be accessed by index.